# Restrict editText from accepting alphabets (in java)?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I defined an EditView in Java and set it to accept numbers. Then it is accepting numbers only, but I needed float values so changed it to following code:

```
final EditText eQuantity = new EditText(getActivity());
                eQuantity.setHint("Enter Quantity here");
                eQuantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

But now it is also accepting alphabets along with float values. Am I missing something over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as:

```
eQuantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | 
                InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | 
                InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but attached docs say nothing about restricting alphabets by using number, signed..